# Does EC2 use ACPI events for anything?

Tags: centos, amazon-ec2

I'm looking at what services I can safely disable on a CentOS image on EC2.
Can I disable acpid? Does EC2 use acpi events for anything?

Answer (score 2):

You need acpid to handle (virtual) power events such as stopping or rebooting the instance.